# Use Lightning Web Component to Create Lead based on Record Type

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-records

Trying to figure out how to pass the recordType into a "CreateRecord" method in a LightningWebComponent. Currently, I'm hard coding the id and passing it with the rest of the values, but that is causing a lead to not get created.

The code is as follows:

```
    leadInput.fields.recordTypeId = '0000000012312'; 
createRecord(leadInput)
        .then(lead => {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    actionName: 'view',
                    recordId: lead.id
                }
            });

            _parent.persons = [
                {
                    recordId: lead.id,
                    name: personName,
                    icon: 'standard:lead'
                }
            ];
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Any insights you can give, would be great. Thanks,